# Display Message only upon validation using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a message appear on the viewport only once all text areas are filled. Right now myMessage appears immediately upon clicking the button on my page even though the first name field has yet to be validated. How do I make the myMessage ONLY appear once the form element for "First Name" is filled out by the user?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitinfo").click(function() {
    var myFirstName = $("#first_name").val().trim();
    if (!myFirstName) {
      $("#first_error").html("You must Enter a First Name");
      $('#first_name').focus();
    } else {
      $("#first_error").html("");
    }
    $("#message").css('background-color', 'red');
    var myMessage = "Your name is " + myFirstName;
    $("#message").html(myMessage);
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"> <span class="error" id="first_error"></span>
<input type="button" id="submitinfo" value="Submit">
<span class="message" id="message"></span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Move the code of the message inside the else block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `myMessage` code inside the `else` block. You'd also want to remove the content of `#message` if `!myFirstName` is true.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are displaying message whenever user clicks the button instead of that display only when user enters something in input field by moving the message block in else part like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitinfo").click(function() {
    var myFirstName = $("#first_name").val().trim();
    if (!myFirstName) {
      $("#first_error").html("You must Enter a First Name");
      $('#first_name').focus();
      $("#message").html("");
    } else {
      $("#first_error").html("");
    $("#message").css('background-color', 'red');
    var myMessage = "Your name is " + myFirstName;
    $("#message").html(myMessage);
    }
    
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"> <span class="error" id="first_error"></span>
<input type="button" id="submitinfo" value="Submit">
<span class="message" id="message"></span>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: where do I put the myMessage code if I have multiple validation fields (IE. If I also had a Last Name Validation Field)? Would I paste the myMessage code in both "else" blocks? Thank you.

Comment: If you want to display specific messages like your first name, your last name then yes you should :)

Comment: Thank you for your help Sanchit, I appreciate it.